# JQuery CSV-export using datatables.net overwrite existing file

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables, export

I'm using jquery datatables for exporting table-values into csv-file like:

```
buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'CSV',
                    extension: '.csv',
                    fieldSeparator: ';',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                        }
                    },
                    title: 'exportfile'
                }]
```

Is there a possibility to overwrite an existing file?

Comment: No. If that were possible it would be a serious security risk.

Comment: Ok. My intension is to use this download for a series letter in Microsoft Word. But this will work only one time, because a new download creates a file with different name....